# remove lines in notepad++ who have the same number on the same line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have for example this lines in notepad++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExD19.png)

```
00100 00100 
00260 00260
01234 01255
```

I want to appear only the lines who have not duplicate numbers. In this case to have in notepad only the line 3. What i need to use in ctrl+h ?

thx

Comment: Do all the lines have two numbers separated by a space?

Comment: yes. The same structure for all lines.

Comment: You'd need a back reference to a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
^(\d+)(?: +)\1 *$
```

and enable regex and add a newline after your last line, this could work.

`^` is the start of a line,  `$` the end of a line

`(\d+)` is 1 to n digits followed by a

`(?: +)` which allowes 1 or more spaces without caputring them

`\1` is a backref to the first number captured.

It wont work for something like

```
0001  00002 00002 0003 0001
```

because 0001 ( the first capture) is not following immediately. This could be alleviated by using this:

```
^(\d+)(?: +)(?:\d* *)*?\1 *$
```

which adds the possibility for non greedy other digits and spaces to matche between the first and a repeating pattern - this will still not work for

```
0001 00002 00002 0003
```

because 00002 is not the first match in a line...

[image: Notepad Example]

Comment: @raduu Feel free to mark it as answer (the grey hoohshape near the number of up/downvotes at top of this answer) if no others pipe it